# How to just convert ArrayList variable to XML using jackson and defining root element by self

Tags: java, jackson

I have been using Jackson to convert Object to XML, but now the requirement is to convert only a variable which is ArrayList from the object to XML. When I wrap the ArrayList into the Object and then convert the Object, It works fine but when I want to simply convert a list to XML. I am not able to get the desired root element and item names in XML.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper();
JacksonXmlModule xmlModule = new JacksonXmlModule();
xmlModule.setDefaultUseWrapper(false);
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new XmlMapper(xmlModule);
objectMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
String xml = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(input);
```

The variable I am trying to convert :

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "user")
List<USER> userList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The output format I am getting right now

```
<ArrayList>
 <item></item>
 <item></item>
 <item></item>
</ArrayList>
```

Desired O/P

```
<ArrayList>
     <user></user>
     <user></user>
     <user></user>
</ArrayList>
```

Answer (score 0):

For re-mapping elements use `@JacksonXmlProperty` and then for wrapping whole list use `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`.

Mapping list elements via `@JacksonXmlProperty`:

```java
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "user")
List<String> userList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Will produce:

```xml
...
<user>...</user>
<user>...</user>
<user>...</user>
...
```

Wrapping the list via `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`:

```java
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "user")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "ArrayList")
List<String> userList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Will produce:

```xml
...
<ArrayList>
  <user>...</user>
  <user>...</user>
  <user>...</user>
</ArrayList>
...
```

Comment: When I am converting the object to XML and the list in that object has these annotations, then only it works perfectly, but I am trying to do is, `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myObject.getUserList());` , In this case, it is not working.

Comment: What's the use-case? I'm afraid such a thing is not possible. It's always more comfortable to work with POJOs. See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jackson-user/hJnU0OaZEfo

Comment: The Use case is: I want to send all these XML as function parameters, And do not want to make a separate DTO containing just a single list.